# File encoding issue in gradle build

Tags: gradle

I run command: 'gradle build'...for a java project I cloned from github.
I get following error for one of the java file:

> error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252

What's the solution for it?

Edit:

[image]

Error is at a comment:

> for example, a network code of “NH” may appear on a “National Highway” or “New Hampshire”.

Error message shows this line as:

> for example, a network code of ΓÇ£NHΓÇ? may appear on a ΓÇ£National HighwayΓÇ? or ΓÇ£New HampshireΓÇ?.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to avoid non ANSI characters in code files. If that is not possible try to save your code files in UTF-8. That should work.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. And I set encoding to 'UTF-8' as shown in image attached to original post.But I still get same issue.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the code file which are making trouble?

Comment: @Mandroid the code lines containing that code are more helpful

Comment: First line is the code. It is actually just a comment in code file, and source of the issue.

Comment: Sorry I see in your question no java code. Just error messages and a screenshot of your IDE settings

Comment: for example, a network code of “NH” may appear on a “National Highway” or “New Hampshire”....this comment in my java code is where error lies.And error displayed in build process is as:for example, a network code of ΓÇ£NHΓÇ? may appear on a ΓÇ£National HighwayΓÇ? or ΓÇ£New HampshireΓÇ?.

Comment: So as you can see, " is causing the issue.

Comment: A string itself is not a valid statement. It should be something like `String foo = "bar";` However it would be great anyway to have some more context.